# GraphicsCaptureItem capture window without user interaction

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, screen-capture

I am writing a C# UWP based screen recorder. When I start capturing I would like to capture without prompting my user to select a window to capture.

At the moment I am needing to do this

```
            var picker = new GraphicsCapturePicker();
            var item = await picker.PickSingleItemAsync();
```

But the above would show a Graphics picker window, then the user can select a window to capture.

I would like to know if there exists a method that will bypass prompting the user to choose a window. Ideally I would like to capture the full window. How can I do this ?

Is this possible ?

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to share your thoughts. As of this time, however, there is no methods or properties of GraphicsCapturePicker class to support bypass prompting the user to choose a window. GraphicsCaptureItem class has no constructors, and the object of GraphicsCaptureItem can only be got from GraphicsCaptureItem.CreateFromVisual(Visual) method or GraphicsCapturePicker.PickSingleItemAsync method.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

check out the new GraphicsCaptureItem.CreateFromVisual() API, which lets your app capture any child window without confirmation.

Comment: Even newer: GraphicsCaptureItem.TryCreateFromWindowId to capture a window, and GraphicsCaptureItem.TryCreateFromDisplayId to capture an entire screen.